# Model fields not displayed

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have an articles table with image, category_id, created-by, updated_by, created_at, updated_at fields. I'm storing article translations in a separate table which has a slug, title, subtitle, description, locale fields.

I want to use seo friendly urls like articles/category-slug/article-slug

I tried the code below in the ArticeController

```
public function show(ArticleCategory $articlecategory, $slug)
{
    $locale = Lang::locale();
    $article = Article::join('article_translations', 'articles.id', '=', 'article_translations.article_id')
    ->where([['slug', $slug], ['locale', $locale]])->with('category')
    ->firstOrFail();
    $article->addPageView();
    return ArticleResource::collection($article);
}
```

old-question(solved by Chris answer) : But it doesn't display all the fields
[image]

I have updated the code above as per suggestions by Chris. However im also using a resource collection and it shows an error with the code above.
Error

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::mapInto does not exist.
```

ArticleResource

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources\Articles;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\ArticleTranslation;

class ArticleResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
          'id' => $this->id,
          'article_url' => '/articles/'.$this->category->slug.'/'.$this->slug,
          'category' => $this->category->name,
          'category_slug' => $this->category->slug,
          'category_url' => '/articles/'.$this->category->slug,
          'image' => url('/').$this->image,
          'author' => $this->creator->name,
          'created' => Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->diffForHumans(),
          'updated' => Carbon::parse($this->updated_at)->diffForHumans(),
          'views' => $this->page_views,
          'title' => $this->title,
          'subtitle' => $this->subtitle,
          'description' => $this->content,
          'links' => [
              'self' => 'link-value',
          ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because you're overridding the fields selected on the `Article` model. Remove the `select` method call.

Comment: Show me your `Article` Model?

Comment: Please revert your question to the original question. You have completely changed the question (including the title). If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: ok. im new to this forum. Ill try a new question

Comment: thats ok. people are just trying to help, and when you change your question dramatically it means the effort they put in is lost

Comment: There was no option of mentioning code in comments so i thought i need to rename the original question till it is solved. Now i understand how this works!

Comment: And i solved it. Resource::collection can be used only hasMany relations. If the model has hasOne relation Resource::make should be used. That solved the error. Every article hasOne Catgeory and that was the thing showing the error. So not creating a new ticket. And accepting your answer as it was the main question i had,

Comment: Nice one and welcome to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the query with a select against only `id` and `slug` so you will always be limited to those fields.

Try:

```
$locale = Lang::locale();
        $article = Article::join('article_translations', 'articles.id', '=', 'article_translations.article_id')
        ->where('slug', $slug)->withTranslations($locale)
        ->firstOrFail();
        $article->addPageView();
        return $article;
```

Comment: Sorry @Srikanth but I rejected that edit request - wrapping it in App make is not the intention of the code above. Did you need to do that for your scenario to work?

Comment: Yes that was the solution for me.